# what is map and reduce phase in search

Tags: search, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I want to use hadoop to implement a simple search engine.

So I created an inverted index using hadoop streaming api and bash.which output a file like this :

```
ab      (744    1)    1
abbrevi (122    1)              1
abil    (51     1)      (77     1)      (738    1)              3
abl     (99     1)      (132    1)      (536    1)      (581    1)      (695    1)      (763    1)      (908    1)      (914    1)      (986    1)      (1114   2)              10
ablat   (82     2)      (274    2)      (553    7)      (587    1)      (1065   3)      (1096   2)      (1097   7)      (1098   3)      (10Sorry if 99   4)      (1100   4)      (1101   3)      (1226   3)      (1241   3)      (1279   1)              14
about   (27     1)      (32     1)      (39     1)      (46     1)      (49     2)      (56     1)      (57     1)      (69     2)      (77     2)      (81
     2)      (83     2)      (113    1)      (134    1)      (139    2)      (140    1)      (155    1)      (156    2)      (162    1)      (163    1)      (165    2)      (171    1)      (174    1)      (177    1)      (193    5)      (205    1)      (206    3)      (212    1)      (216    3)      (218    1)
      (225    2)      (249    3)      (255    1)      (257    1)      (262    1)      (266    3)      (272    6)      (273    1)      (285    1)      (292
    2)      (313    1)      (315    2)      (346    2)      (368    1)      (370    1)      (371    1)      (372    1)      (373    1)      (381    2)      (391    1)      (410    3)      (420    1)      (452    1)      (456    4)      (469    1)      (479    1)      (489    1)      (498    3)      (511    1)
      (518    1)      (531    1)      (536    1)      (548    1)      (555    1)      (556    1)      (560    2)      (565    1)      (567    1)      (572
    1)      (575    1)      (577    1)      (589    1)      (601    1)      (603    1)      (610    1)      (612    1)      (614    1)      (620    1)      (621    4)      (625    3)      (626    1)      (646    1)      (649    1)      (651    2)      (657    2)      (662    1)      (679    1)      (685    2)
      (686    1)      (704    2)      (706    2)      (709    1)      (717    2)      (721    1)      (740    2)      (757    2)      (759    1)      (774
    1)      (786    1)      (792    2)      (793    1)      (794    2)      (796    2)      (801    2)      (805    1)      (806    1)      (807    2)      (808    2)      (811    1)      (815    1)      (816    1)      (829    2)      (844    1)      (869    1)      (876    1)      (912    1)      (917    1)
      (921    1)      (927    1)      (928    2)      (958    1)      (976    6)      (991    1)      (992    2)      (993    1)      (994    1)      (996
    1)      (999    1)      (1000   1)      (1002   1)      (1004   2)      (1006   1)      (1040   1)      (1092   1)      (1095   2)      (1104   4)      (1105   1)      (1115   1)      (1143   4)      (1156   2)      (1162   1)      (1164   3)      (1165   1)      (1166   3)      (1169   1)      (1191   1)
      (1194   1)      (1202   1)      (1209   1)      (1212   1)      (1218   1)      (1223   1)      (1224   1)      (1229   1)      (1230   1)      (1231
   1)      (1239   1)      (1241   1)      (1244   1)      (1246   1)      (1248   1)      (1255   2)      (1262   1)      (1275   2)      (1282   1)      (1303   1)      (1304   1)      (1307   1)      (1310   3)      (1316   1)      (1335   1)      (1341   1)      (1344   1)      (1345   1)      (1353   1)
      (1354   3)      (1355   1)      (1363   1)      (1377   1)              178
```

It means for example word `ab` repeated only once in document number 744.
Now I want to implement `and query searching` (which means the document should contains all words in query) using hadoop streaming api.

so what exactly is map and reduce phase in search? and also can you please give me some hints how can I implement it using streaming api? (what should be the input field? ), and I don't have any idea what to do?)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my take on your query search problem- I'm just giving you a rough overview of what should be done, rather than giving you the code (my bash skills are a bit rusty anyway).

**Job Setup**

First you will need to tokenize the query, put the list of tokens as a comma separated list into a config value. You can do this on the mapper/reducer side if you like, but I would recommend to centralize this part in the job setup.

**Mapper**

Read the config value from the query, make it a "set" or some other structure that has fast key lookups.

The mapper should map each line (a word to n-documents) and if the current word in this line is in your query set, "emit" it to HDFS. This stage should emit the document-id as a key with each word as the value (this creates "n" output records, where "n" is the number of documents per word).

**Reducer**

The reducer then receives a document-id as key and multiple tokens that matched your query as values, now you read the config value again and just compare if you got all the tokens from your query in this document.

You should emit the document-id as key and usually in search you output some "match-score" as the value. In your case you only search for "full" matches, so this score actually doesn't matter as it will be a constant.

**Some improvements**

Think of some improvements after doing this, in this case the Mapper emits all the tokens- do you really need them as separate records? Maybe you can use a combiner to save some network bandwidth?

I leave those as an exercise for the reader ;-)